# Bootstrap Modal Popup Issue

Tags: modal-dialog

I have developed MVC application with Bootstrap CSS and facing weird issue in which during Modal open in application all controls repeated twice in two separate DIV contain class "modal" and "modal in" respectively.

Due to above behavior my application modal popup rendering is too slow as it contain too many HTML controls and i have to open this application in IE only.

Please find below screen shot in which you can see same control repeated in two different DIV.

[Highlighted Part contain Two DIV with class "Modal" and "Modal in" respectively](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXsGI.png)

Please help me out on this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: my guess you put same modal HTML code twice

Comment: No HTML code is not repeated on page. I have used Partial control which will render on Modal when Modal is open from page.

Comment: Apart from this one more thing i have notice if i search in IE console by control ID then it will give me only one control but if i assign class to same control and search by class in IE console then it will return two controls. Please suggest

Comment: Thanks all for your help. I figured out issue and on page i have put two different modal in different DIV but assign same class which cause this issue. I have change class name for those DIV and now it will work properly.